# unexpected behavior pandas groupby transform

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am reading the 'Python for Data Analysis' book and I was working through an example as prototyped below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2, 3], 'b' : [3,4,6]}, index=['AA', 'BB', 'CC'])

In [313]: df1
Out[313]: 
    a  b
AA  1  3
BB  2  4
CC  3  6

In [314]: df1.groupby(['one', 'two', 'one']).mean()
Out[314]: 
     a    b
one  2  4.5
two  2  4.0
```

Now, when I use `transform(np.mean)` on the `DataFrame`, I am getting:

```
In [315]: df1.groupby(['one', 'two', 'one']).transform(np.mean)
Out[315]: 
      a    b
AA  NaN  NaN
BB  NaN  NaN
CC  NaN  NaN
one   2  4.5
two   2  4.0
```

Based on the book and documentation, I should get

```
      a    b
AA    2  4.5
BB    2  4.0
CC    2  4.5
```

Can somebody explain am I doing something wrong, or has there been a change in behavior of `pandas transform`

For reference for people who have the book, a similar example is on Page 265, Python for Data Analysis" ([http://www.amazon.com/Python-Data-Analysis-Wrangling-IPython/dp/1449319793/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414333292&sr=8-1&keywords=python+for+data+analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319793))

EDIT:

This is the actual example in the book.

```
people = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('abcde'), index=['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis'])

people.ix[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = np.nan

key = ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one']

people.groupby(key).transform(np.mean)
```

This should display averages by key in a dataframe with `index =  ['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis']` and `columns = list("abcde")`

instead I get.

```
               a         b         c         d         e
Jim          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Joe          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Steve        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Travis       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
Wes          NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
one     0.115921  0.269327 -0.812230  0.901449  0.100471
two    -1.371846 -0.918605 -0.391085 -0.425853  0.436742
```

I am actually using pandas version 0.14.1.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example with pandas `0.15.0`. I get the result from the book, but with all values set to `4` in the `b` column.
Doesn't this example violate the contract of the transform function? The docs state: `Thus, the passed transform function should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk.`

Comment: In case my prototype example is not correct, I have added the actual example. Thanks. I will also update my pandas and see if that helps.

Comment: this was a bug that appeared only in 0.14.1 (prior to and post it is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Updating my pandas version fixed the issue. It might have been a bug in the previous version. But not sure.